# Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lex failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, ios7, tesseract

I am trying to include a file in my resource bundle the files contains the following:

```
LeadPunc="({[`'
TrailPunc=}:;-]!?`,.)"'
NumLeadPunc=#({[@$
NumTrailPunc=}):;].,%
Operators=*+-/.:,()[]
Digits=0123456789
Alphas=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
*extra line*
```

The files is called:

```
eng.cube.lm
```

The error I get is:

```
IExpenseReporter/tessdata/eng.cube.lm:6: premature EOF
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lex failed with exit code 1
```

This file goes along with the newest version of tesseract (OCR). Does anyone have an idea what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: i have the same problem are u resolve the problem plz ans me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode "thinks" this is a [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) file and try to process it by calling lex. However, lex finds and unbalanced quote and thus a premature end of file.

You should try to call the designated tool explicitly.

Comment: iam getting the same issue can you please help me to resolve the issue i'm unable to understand your answer

Comment: I've never worked with tesseract thus I'm not sure, how to process the file. But to avoid the error, deactivate the lex rule or mark the file as not belonging to your project.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you select the "Create folder references" option when adding the tessdata folder to your project.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/wiki/Installation):

> NOTE: This library currently requires the tessdata folder to be linked
>   as a referenced folder instead of a symbolic group. If Tesseract can't
>   find a language file in your own project, it's probably because you
>   created the tessdata folder as a symbolic group instead of a
>   referenced folder. It should look like this if you did it correctly:
>
> [image]
>
> Note how the tessdata folder has a blue icon, indicating it was
>   imported as a referenced folder instead of a symbolic group.

Trashing the current folder and adding it again as a folder reference should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I found that copying the folder "tessdata" from the language zip into the project directory rather then into Xcode fixed the issue.